# How to specify the URL to return to after a successfull login with Auth0 and Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, auth0

My Blazor App runs on https://localhost:5001/app

But after I log in, Auth0 always returns to https://localhost:5001

How can I change that?

Here is how I register the service:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Auth0", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalProviderParameters.Add("audience", (string)builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"]!);
    options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalProviderParameters.Add("prompt", "select_account");
    // options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalProviderParameters.Add("returnTo", "https://localhost:5001/app"); <== NOT WORKING
});
```

And here is my Authentication component:

```
@page "/app/authentication/{action}"

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject NavigationManager Nav

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded=@loginHandler OnLogOutSucceeded=@logoutHandler>
    <LogOut>
        @{
            var authority = (string)Configuration["Auth0:Authority"]!;
            var clientId = (string)Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]!;
            var returnTo = "https://localhost:5001/app";
            Nav.NavigateTo($"{authority}/v2/logout?client_id={clientId}&returnTo={returnTo}");
        }
    </LogOut>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Action { get; set; }

    private void loginHandler() {}
    private void logoutHandler() {}
}
```

Comment: try adding `Nav.NavigateTo("/app");` in your `loginHandler()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try as below:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "{Your target url}";
    
});
```

I misunderstood your requirement at first, now I reproduced the issue successfully

Solved the issue based on RBee's comment(the RemoteAuthenticatorView Component would redirect you to "/" by default,to avoid this, you have to set forceload to ture):

```
@page "/app/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Nav

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="@LoginSucceeded" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Action { get; set; }
    

    

    public void LoginSucceeded()
    {
        Nav.NavigateTo("/app",true);
    }

    
}
```

It's ok now:
[image]

Comment: I already defined the `RedirectUri` option in the `Auth0` configuration (in appsettings.json), as follow: `"RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5001/app/authentication/login-callback"`, I think that is how it is usually done.

Comment: Oh，Sorry Ireproduced succseefully,when I tried with another url starts with "app" at first,it works well,when I tried with with your url ,the issue occured.

Comment: I don't really get you, which case is working, please?

Comment: I don't really get you, which case is working, please?--at first,I set the redirect url as "/app/Index",it works well, then I tried with your url:"app/authentication/login-callback",the issue occoured due to the RemoteAuthenticatorView Component would redirect you agian to "/" by default